# $ bundle install --path /cache Could not locate Gemfile

Tags: ruby, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

When trying to run a build with GitLab CI the error

```
$ bundle install --path /cache
Could not locate Gemfile
```

Is thrown.

The .gitlab-ci.yml file is here

```
Test:
  script:
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y nodejs
  - bundle install --path /cache
  - bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test
  - bundle exec rake test

staging:
  type: deploy
  script:
  - gem install dpl
  - dpl --provider=heroku --app=gitlab-ci-ruby-test-staging --api-key=$HEROKU_STAGING_API_KEY
  only:
  - master

production:
  type: deploy
  script:
  - gem install dpl
  - dpl --provider=heroku --app=gitlab-ci-ruby-test-prod --api-key=$HEROKU_PRODUCTION_API_KEY
  only:
  - tags
```

Any advise on solving this would be most appreciated!

Comment: Is your `Gemfile` added to your repo?

Comment: Two shots in the dark:


1. should that be `vendor/cache` instead?

2. make sure `/cache` isn't part of your .gitignore file

Comment: I know `bundle cache` used to be a thing to place bundled gems into your repo, which is why I'm putting this out there.